# kubernetes on virtualbox and visual studio code

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have installed kuberenetes with minikube on windows in virtualbox, for the moment I'm using visual studio as yaml IDE and using cmd for kubectl commands.

I want to know how can I define Visual studio to connect to minikube inside itself and discard the cmd?
Is there any extension or other tools?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. You can ask questions about developer tools on our sister site [so].

Answer (score 1):

You need Install the Kubernetes extension , follow guide
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-kubernetes-tools.vscode-kubernetes-tools